# Edge Transport cmdlet

Tags: exchange-2013, exchange

I am trying to upgrade my Exchange 2007 setup with Mailbox/CAB/Hub server, (and edge server), to a fully Exchange 2013 setup.

I have Exchange 2013 Mailbox server setup, running and working, (on win2012R2 VM in my AD domain), and I have successfully migrated some of the mailboxes to the new 2013 mail server.
 I have also successfully installed Exchange 2013 in Edge Transport role, on another win2012R2 VM, as a stand-alone server, and created an edge subscription on the edge transport box and imported it successfully on the new Exchange 2013 Mailbox server, using the commands:

```
[byte[]]$Temp = Get-Content -Path "C:\EdgeServerSubscription.xml" -Encoding Byte -ReadCount 0
New-EdgeSubscription -FileData $Temp -Site "Default-First-Site-Name"
```

Now I wpould like to test what I've done, to ensure that it is all ok... So I ran

```
Get-EdgeSubscription | Format-List
```

on the new exchange 2013 mailbox server.  There are a few things in the output that I do not understand.

1. Why is the old Exchange 2007 edge subscription (the first one in the
   output) still showing? It should only be wired up between the old
   Exchange 2007 edge server and the old Exchange 2007 mailbox server.
   Is it wired up to the new Exchange 2013 mailbox server too?
2. The item labeled "Originating Server", (which reads
   ELSINORE.myDomain.com), is the Hyper-V host server for the two old
   VMs hosting the two Exchange 2007 servers, which I will hopefully be
   removing completely from the system. Why is this listed here? What
   does it mean? Why is it in the section for the new Edge subscription
   (the second one)?
3. Should the old Exchange 2007 artifacts even be listed here?

   RunspaceId        : guidguid-guid-guid-guid-guidguidguid
   Site              : myDomain.com/Configuration/Sites/Default-First-Site-Name
   Domain            : myDomain.com
   Identity          : Edge
   IsValid           : True
   ExchangeVersion   : 0.1 (8.0.535.0)
   Name              : Edge
   DistinguishedName : CN=Edge,CN=Servers,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=AreteOrg,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=myDomain,DC=com
   Guid              : guidguid-guid-guid-guid-guidguidguid
   ObjectCategory    : myDomain.com/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Exchange-Server
   ObjectClass       : {top, server, msExchExchangeServer}
   WhenChanged       : 1/21/2011 5:50:26 PM
   WhenCreated       : 1/21/2011 5:50:25 PM
   WhenChangedUTC    : 1/22/2011 1:50:26 AM
   WhenCreatedUTC    : 1/22/2011 1:50:25 AM
   OrganizationId    :
   **OriginatingServer : ELSINORE.myDomain.com**
   ObjectState       : Unchanged

   RunspaceId        : guidguid-guid-guid-guid-guidguidguid
   Site              : myDomain.com/Configuration/Sites/Default-First-Site-Name
   Domain            : myDomain.com
   Identity          : Hermes
   IsValid           : True
   ExchangeVersion   : 0.1 (8.0.535.0)
   Name              : Hermes
   DistinguishedName : CN=Hermes,CN=Servers,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=myDomainOrg,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=myDomain,DC=com
   Guid              : guidguid-guid-guid-guid-guidguidguid
   ObjectCategory    : myDomain.com/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Exchange-Server
   ObjectClass       : {top, server, msExchExchangeServer}
   WhenChanged       : 4/10/2014 2:51:30 PM
   WhenCreated       : 4/10/2014 2:51:30 PM
   WhenChangedUTC    : 4/10/2014 9:51:30 PM
   WhenCreatedUTC    : 4/10/2014 9:51:30 PM
   OrganizationId    :
   **OriginatingServer : ELSINORE.myDomain.com**
   ObjectState       : Unchanged